# How to write destructor for deleting a tree where each node is a dynamically allocated structure containing several arrays?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class that contains a structure called **Node** and memory for this is dynamically allocated. Using the **add** function I am creating more Node and connectin them through the **next** **array** pointers. I am only saving my **head pointer**, which points to my first node. I am trying to write a destructor like below. Is it ok?

```
struct Node{
    bool arr[30];
    bool end[30];
    Node* next[30];
};

class ClassName{
    Node  *head;
    Node* newNode(){
        Node * cur = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        return cur;
    }
public:
    ClassName(){
        head = newNode();
    }
    ~ClassName(){
        free(head);
    }
    void add(string s,int pos,Node *cur){// 1 base index
        // adding new node and next array pointers will connect them
        // So after adding some nodes it will form like a tree
    }
};
```

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` and `free` instead of `new` and `delete`?

Comment: *Using the add function I am creating more Node and connectin them through the next array pointers.* -- Your `Node` isn't intuitive as to showing what you're actually trying to achieve -- describing what `add` is supposed to do is not enough information.  We need to actually see what `add` does.

Comment: And if you would use `new` and `delete` I'd ask why not using a [smart pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) instead?

Comment: The destructors going recursive with smart pointers has bitten me a few times with large graphs. Make sure the size of the graph will be small enough that you can't, or are unlikely to, overflow the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
~ClassName(){
    free(head);
}
```

This frees the head node. It doesn't also free any of the nodes referred to by `head->next[0..29]`. So no, it's not OK if you actually allocated those nodes - you will have a memory leak.

Next problem, your `next` array is uninitialized, so unless it's *always* all populated (which is obviously impossible as your tree would have no leaves), there's no way to figure out which entries are real pointers and which are garbage values. So it's impossible to fix this leak with the code as shown.

We could fix the existing `malloc` code to properly initialize your objects, but it brings us on to the next oddity, which is using `malloc` and `free` for objects in C++ at all.

Using `new` and `delete` would be a modest improvement (at least `Node` could have a constructor and destructor to properly initialize and destroy itself), but switching to owning smart pointers instead of raw pointers would be best: they initialize and destroy themselves automatically with no extra work on your part.

```
struct Node{
    // value-initialize all those bools to false
    bool arr[30] {};
    bool end[30] {};
    // this will initialize all entries to nullptr, and
    // also takes care of deleting them on destruction
    std::array<std::unique_ptr<Node>, 30> next;
};

    std::unique_ptr<Node> ClassName::newNode() {
        return std::make_unique<Node>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to use smart pointers. But if you would like to stick to built-in pointers, it is also very easy to achieve the goal. You only need to add a simple one-liner destructor for every class, and make sure every destructor frees memory at its own level. Then the class relationship guarantees that the memory are freed in a recursive postorder manner. The beauty of this approach is that you don't have to write a recursive postorder traversal yourself. The destructors recurse themselves.

Add the following destructor for `Node` class:

```
~Node() {
    for (Node *p : next) {
        delete p;
    }
}
```

Use the following destructor for `ClassName` class:

```
~ClassName(){
    delete head;
}
```

A note: To verify that the nodes on the tree are freed in a postorder manner, you may add a print statement after each delete statement.